# Is Spark 3.3.2, that can run under Java 17, able to manage records?

Tags: java, apache-spark, record

I have a method:

```java
public Dataset<ActiviteCommune> activitesParCommune(Dataset<Row> rowEntreprisesEtablissements) {
   return rowEntreprisesEtablissements
     .map((MapFunction<Row, ActiviteCommune>) row -> {
        try {
           // Déterminer la section associée au code APE.
           String siren = row.getAs("siren");
           String siret = row.getAs("siret");
           String codeAPE = row.getAs("activitePrincipale");
           [...]
              
           return new ActiviteCommune(codeCommune, epci, nomCommune, strateCommune, codeAPE, section, 
              1, nombreSalaries, nombreActifs, siren, nomEntreprise, siret, 
              nomEtablissement, categorieJuridique, libelleAPE, estimationFournieParINSEE, libelleCategorieJuridique, 
              categorieEntreprise, categorieEtablissement);
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e) {
           String format = "Un row durant le mapDetailActivites(..) a provoqué un incident : {0}. Contenu du row : \n{1}";
           String message = MessageFormat.format(format, e.getMessage(), row.mkString());
           RuntimeException ex = new RuntimeException(message, e);
              
           LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
           throw ex;
        }
     }, Encoders.bean(ActiviteCommune.class));
}
```

with a POJO:

```java
public class ActiviteCommune implements Serializable {
   /** Serial ID. */
   @Serial
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 3283834279341212821L;
   
   /** Code de la commune. */
   private String codeCommune;
   
   /** Code EPCI de l'intercommunalité. */
   private String codeEPCI;
   
   /** Nom de la commune */
   private String nomCommune;

   public ActiviteCommune(String codeCommune, String codeEPCI, String nomCommune, Integer strateCommune, String ape, String section, 
         int nombreEntreprises, double nombreSalaries, double nombreActifs, String siren, String nomEntreprise, String siret, 
         String nomEtablissement, String categorieJuridique, String libelleAPE, boolean estimationFournie, String libelleCategorieJuridique,
         String categorieEntreprise, String categorieEtablissement) {
      [...]
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code APE de l'activité exercée.
    * @return Code APE.
    */
   public String getApe() {
      return this.ape;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code APE de l'activité exercée.
    * @param ape Code APE.
    */
   public void setApe(String ape) {
      this.ape = ape;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer la catégorie d'entreprise : PME, ETI, GE (INSEE).
    * @return Catégorie d'entreprise.
    */
   public String getCategorieEntreprise() {
      return this.categorieEntreprise;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer la catégorie d'entreprise : PME, ETI, GE (INSEE).
    * @param categorieEntreprise Catégorie d'entreprise.
    */
   public void setCategorieEntreprise(String categorieEntreprise) {
      this.categorieEntreprise = categorieEntreprise;
   }
   [...]
```

that works, and returns a Dataset of the wished `ActiviteCommune` objects

But then I've attempted an:

```java
public Dataset<JeuDeDonnees> catalogueDataset(Dataset<Row> datasets) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(datasets, "Le Dataset en entrée ne peut pas valoir null.");

   return datasets
      .map((MapFunction<Row, JeuDeDonnees>)row -> {
         try {
            String catId = row.getAs("id_catalogue");
            CatalogueId catalogueId = catId != null ? new CatalogueId(catId) : null;

            String titre = row.getAs("titre_catalogue");
            String slug = row.getAs("slug_catalogue");
            [...]

            return new JeuDeDonnees(catalogueId, titre, slug, acronyme, url,
               organisationId, organisation, description, frequence, licence,
               dateDebut, dateFin, granulariteSpatiale, zonesSpatiales, prive,
               featured, dateCreation, dateModification, tags, archive,
               nombreDeRessources, metriqueDiscussions, metriqueReutilisation, metriqueSuiveurs, metriqueVues);
         }
         catch(RuntimeException e) {
            String format = "Un row durant le mapCatalogueDataset(..) a provoqué un incident : {0}. Contenu du row : \n{1}";
            String message = MessageFormat.format(format, e.getMessage(), row.mkString());
            RuntimeException ex = new RuntimeException(message, e);

            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw ex;
         }
      }, Encoders.bean(JeuDeDonnees.class));
}
```

with another Java POJO that is a Record, and not a Class

```java
public record JeuDeDonnees(CatalogueId catalogueId, String titre, String slug, String acronyme, String url,
   OrganisationId organisationId, String organisation, String description, String frequence, String licence,
   LocalDate dateDebut, LocalDate dateFin, String granulariteSpatiale, String zonesSpatiales, Boolean prive,
   Boolean featured, LocalDate dateCreation, LocalDate dateModification, String tags, Boolean archive,
   Integer nombreDeRessources, Integer metriqueDiscussions, Integer metriqueReutilisation, Integer metriqueSuiveurs, Integer metriqueVues) {
}
```

My Spark 3.3.2 fails :

```
2023-04-24 14:27:53.645  INFO 653527 --- [           main] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : Job 6 finished: takeAsList at CatalogueDatagouvIT.java:88, took 0,036174 s
2023-04-24 14:27:53.666 ERROR 653527 --- [           main] o.a.s.s.c.e.codegen.CodeGenerator        : failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 8: No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "fr.ecoemploi.metier.catalogue.JeuDeDonnees(fr.ecoemploi.metier.catalogue.CatalogueId, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, fr.ecoemploi.metier.catalogue.OrganisationId, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)"

org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 8: No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "fr.ecoemploi.metier.catalogue.JeuDeDonnees(fr.ecoemploi.metier.catalogue.CatalogueId, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, fr.ecoemploi.metier.catalogue.OrganisationId, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)"
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:12021)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.findMostSpecificIInvocable(UnitCompiler.java:9332)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.invokeConstructor(UnitCompiler.java:8035)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileGet2(UnitCompiler.java:5430)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$9800(UnitCompiler.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$16.visitNewClassInstance(UnitCompiler.java:4494)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$16.visitNewClassInstance(UnitCompiler.java:4455)
```

`Spark 3.3.2` is able to work with Java 17.

But do you now if it is able to handle records, already?